# iOS: Uniquely identify ViewControllers from Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom `ViewController` that is meant to be reusable, and an arbitrary number of instances will be chained together in a `NavigationController` in Storyboard, all sharing the same model as a delegate.

The `ViewController`s need to tell the model which instance they are. Currently, they have an int property that they get from the segue, but it doesn't seem very idiomatic and doesn't lend itself to having multiple instances onscreen (for iPad). I figure there's got to be a cleaner way to do this, so does anyone know what it is? Thanks.

RESULT: self.view.tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A UIViewController's UIView has a `tag` property which you can set from anywhere you want. You could also simply identify the type of the controller by using `[self class]`. Or simply use the memory location by referencing the controller directly.

Update You could simply implement a unique identifier for a UIViewController using a category.

Comment: The `identifier` looked promising, but it does not appear to in fact be a property of UIViewController. These are instances of the same class, so `[self class]` won't work, and the memory location changes if the controller is de- and  re- allocated.

Comment: @mgold Oh, turns out there's actually no identifier in the controller. Strange, because Xcode did show it in the IB. I'd recommend implementing it yourself, by using a protocol which all controllers implement. Also: `identifier` is also gone once you deallocate, and I'm pretty sure that memory addresses never shift during normal operations.

Comment: That's basically what I do, but I can't find a good way to set the identifier. Using a field in SToryboard/IB would be ideal since the instances are already laid out.

Comment: The `UIView` (`[controller view]`) has a `tag` property which you can use (and probably set in the IB). This is a `NSInteger`

Comment: @Till It doesn't seem to have a `tag` property either. Closest thing is `title`, but I'm looking for a machine-readable equivalent (ideally and int that can be used to index into and `NSArray`). EDIT: Oh, the view itself. Will look into. [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @mgold my bad, I did not properly edit the posting - please reload and see if it makes more sense now.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt yes, I should have done that in the first place. Please accept my apologies. Gee, you know, I felt you were so close with your answer that correcting it would make it perfect.

Comment: @Till That looks like it will work, but I'll need a few minutes to code it up and make sure. Another reason to add your own answer is that I can accept it and give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "cleanest" way in terms of design architecture would perhaps be an array of ViewControllers. (It could be managed in the app delegate.) However, there are memory considerations - on the iPhone you would likely want to create and the destroy the view controllers as needed. The array could contain the `identifier` and perhaps some other model-related information in order to recreated the controllers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad there is no property `storyboardIdentifier` of UIViewController. They can be instantiated with this id but it would be helpful if the viewcontroller can query its id.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this. I figured out you can add a "Restoration ID" in the storyboard. Then you can access it perhaps like this (depending on your use case)

```
navigationController?.viewControllers.first?.restorationIdentifier
```